# Why is deciding regularity of a context-free language undecidable?

Tags: formal-languages, computability, regular-languages, undecidability

As I have studied, deciding regularity of context-free languages is undecidable.

However, we can test for regularity using the Myhill–Nerode theorem which provides a necessary and sufficient condition. So the problem should be decidable.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: How do you propose to tell whether the Myhill-Nerode relation has a finite number of equivalence classes? What property of context-free languages do you think allows you to do that?

Comment: Please check the definition of computability: you need to give a *Turing machine* (or, more generally, an algorithm) that solves the problem (always). Myhill-Nerode is, per se, not an algorithm, only a characterisation. Is the provided property decidable? Have you tried transforming the theorem into such an algorithm?

Comment: Thanks for editing and reply. By your comment I can understand that Myhill Nerode theorem is not computable Because of that we cant decide regularity.

But here one more basic doubt is coming, Till Now I was thinking that using Myhill we can decide the regularity. If it is not than How can we decide regularity or it is also undecidable?

Comment: @Jiya What do you mean by "decide regularity"? At first, it seems obvious what that means but it's actually more subtle. A decision procedure (algorithm) must take a finite input so how would you give an infinite language as input? Maybe you want to use expressions such as $\{a^nb^n\mid n\ge 0\}$. OK, but what expressions will you allow? $\{a^nb^m\mid \text{the }m\text{th Turing machine halts on input }m\}$? $\{a^nb^{kn}\mid k\text{ is one of David Richerby's favourite numbers}\}$?

Comment: PS. A nice characterization is not perse decidable. Most clear example is that equality to $\Sigma^*$ is not decidable for context-free languages.

Comment: @David Yes My mean of "decide regularity" is to have a Turing machine which can accept a language and can tell us the final result. That is what you have already explained.

Comment: @David when you say that I cant pass expression in input due to limitation, then it makes some problem in my understanding because I think I can pass any expression for example scientific calculator. Where you can give expressions too.What I am trying to say is , Cant we have a expression parser like thing in Input?

Comment: @Jiya Absolutely, yes. But you have to choose what set of expressions you want to accept and write a formal specification of those expressions. Then, your Turing machine would have to parse the expressions and decide whether they correspond to regular languages or not.

Comment: @David as your example we can take input like a^x.b^y.c^wz.
Here I am just asking for Input not for TM.
Because as you said it is not possible to have a TM which can check for regularity.

Comment: @Jiya Without any relationships between $x$, $y$ and $z$, the language defined by $a^xb^yc^z$ is regular -- it's just $a^*b^*c^*$. So you'd need to say what relationships can be expressed; and you might want to be able to express languages where the strings aren't just some number of $a$s followed by some number of $b$s followed by some number of $c$s.

Comment: @David I think we can define relationship like a^x.b^2x or a^x.b^2x.c^x.And you said "you might want to be able to express languages where the strings aren't just some number" , Can you give me some example for this kind of string?

Comment: @Jiya If the only languages you consider are the ones of the form $\{a^{kx}b^{\ell x}c^{mx}|x\ge 0\}$ where $k$, $\ell$ and $m$ are constants, then the resulting language is regular if, and only if, two or three of $k$, $\ell$ and $m$ are zero. So, for languages defined that way, the problem of determining whether the resulting language is regular *is* decidable. But, if you allow more complex relationships between the numbers of $a$s, $b$s and $c$s, it can be undecidable whether a language is regular. This is why it is crucially important how the languages are specified.

Comment: @Jiya I said "languages where the strings aren't just some number of $a$s followed by some number of $b$s followed by some number of $c$s". For example, the language $\{ww\mid w\in a^*b^*\}$.

Comment: @David Ya thanks this time I understood clearly, this example made it clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Myhill–Nerode does indeed provide a characterization of the regular languages but that isn't enough to show that the problem is decidable.  "Decidable" means that there is an algorithm (more formally, a Turing machine) that terminates for every input and, of course, always gives the correct answer.  So, in this case, you would need to give an algorithm that, given a language as input, determines whether the Myhill–Nerode relation has a finite number of equivalence classes.  It turns out that this cannot be done for context-free languages; details in your favourite formal languages textbook.

If you want to decide whether a general language is regular, a further subtlety is that you have to be careful about what is the input to your algorithm. The input must be a finite string – otherwise, even just reading the input would be a non-terminating algorithm.  In the case of context-free languages, you could use a grammar as a finite representation of an infinite language.  For more general languages, you would need... well, something more general.  Ultimately, though, if you want to deal with *all* languages, you're doomed.  Over any finite alphabet, there are uncountably many languages but only countably many finite strings. That means you can't possibly describe all languages using finite strings.<sup>1</sup> Therfore, trying to write an algorithm to determine whether arbitrary languages given as input are regular actually fails before it begins. It's not just that you can't write the algorithm: you can't even write the input!

Note that this doesn't mean that you, a human being, can't use Myhill–Nerode to determine whether languages are regular. It just means that you can't write down a set of precise instructions to tell *me* how to do that.  At some point, any such set of instructions would have to say something like, "And then play about with it to see what works," or "From there, you have to figure it out on your own."

---

1. In particular, this means that some languages must be undecidable, since there are more languages than there are algorithms.

Comment: We can circumvent the problem with input encoding by restricting ourselves to all recursively enumerable, or decidable, or even context-free languages. Then, we have "natural" input encodings (grammars, Turing machines, ...) but *still* can not decide regularity. So, clearly, there are more subtle things afoot.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. I've edited to make it clearer that the "doom" section referred to not being able to accept all languages as inputs.